# Magento 2 - Duplicate Order Issue

Tags: magento2, checkout, orders, payment-methods

I am currently running a **magento 2 website (ver. 2.2.6)**.  I have been an issue (pretty frequently) where some customers (not all) are reporting that they are commonly receiving an error upon attempting to **submit an order**.  The error that they receive is:

```
sort order field isnull(expiration_date), expiration_date, transaction_id contains restricted symbols
```

The customer(s) report that this error appears when they click on submit order, and the website never goes to the **checkout success page**.  Therefore the customer thinks that the website did not receive their order.  They then proceed to click on **submit order multiple times**, subsequently placing multiple orders.  I catch these with the **payment alerts** or the customer sends an email reporting that they just placed 8 orders by mistake.  Commonly, the customer reports being on a mobile device, and this happens with both **paypal and/or credit card (Stripe processing)**.

I have also been advised that sometimes they do not get this error, but the site just looks like it does nothing and remains on the **checkout page** when they click on submit order, also subsequently placing multiple orders.

When I go to the backend of the site, I do see an order placed that matches the payment obtained from the customer, through the **payment processor**.  The problem is, I can not re-create this issue myself so it has been extremely difficult to trouble shoot.  As I have paid 2 separate developers to try and resolve this, with no success.

I am looking for some help with this issue, as it is causing many issues, and upsetting many customers.  Thanks!  Below is an image of the error, provided by a customer.
[image]

Comment: Are you using Aheadworks Reward Points for Magento 2 extension by any chance?

Answer (score 0):

You should be using Aheadworks_RewardPoints module.

Go to the file `/app/code/Aheadworks/RewardPoints/Model/Service/CustomerRewardPointsService.php`.

Search for the method `private function getCustomerTransactions`.

Change `->setField('ISNULL(expiration_date), expiration_date, transaction_id')` line

to `->setField('expiration_date')`.